# Login to azure devops account from xcode

Tags: xcode, azure, azure-devops

How do I sign in to Azure devops accounts from xcode preferences. The account for Azure doesn't show up. The code is already hosted on Azure Devops and I was working on an already made project and the repo is already in the azure devops account. The previous account was obselete and now I need to login to my own account to push the changes. Whenever I am trying to push and commit the changes I get an error:

> remote: You are not authorized to access this collection. (-20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to get into the same folder as the project and then use git
git config --local user.email "yourmail@example.com"

git config --local user.name "yourName"

then while pushing the code it asked for password where I provided one from azure and it worked.
You can get the token from repository. Please check the screenshot. [image]